# Can't consume .NET web service in ColdFusion MX

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

We are trying to consume an ASP.NET web service from our CF box and are running into odd issues.

```
<cfinvoke webservice="http://myserver.mine.com/myservice.asmx?WSDL" method="ImportData" returnvariable="ImportDataCompleted">
<cfinvokeargument name="importJobName" value="job1">
<cfinvokeargument name="force" value="false">
```

If we run this from a version 9 box, it will work just fine, however, when I run on MX, I get the following error:

> Could not perform web service invocation "ImportData" because AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}VersionMismatch faultSubcode: faultString: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://www.w3.org/2002/12/soap-envelope was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace: AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}VersionMismatch faultSubcode: faultString: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://www.w3.org/2002/12/soap-envelope was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://www.w3.org/2002/12/soap-envelope was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:260) at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:169) at org.ap...

I have cleared the web services in the administrator, and they do repopulate, but still the error.  Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is happening because the version of MX you're using is running SOAP 1.1 and ColdFusion 9 is running SOAP 1.2. (Note the text in your error: *Possible SOAP version mismatch*.)

I'm not familiar with SOAP, but it looks like there are [some other differences](http://wso2.org/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message) between the two that you might want to read about. There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393680/coldfusion-webservice-call-help-please) that suggests that earlier versions of CF, at least, do not (or did not) support 1.2.

Comment: Some more digging brought us to this conclusion as well.  We also found some references to what version of soap each server side loanguauge was using ( i will post when i find again)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ColdFusion MX 6.1, you will not be able to consume web services using the cfinvoke tag. The engineers at Adobe/Macromedia didn't include that functionality until CFMX 7.

You will be required to use Java stubs.  See this [link](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/039/eaf0396.html).

Once you have created the stubs you need to compile them using Java 1.4 (you can use ColdFusion's internal jdk to do so). Then, create a jar file and deploy it to you instance of ColdFusion, normally ./runtime/lib/. Restart ColdFusion and create an object using CFObject.  Then call the web service's methods using the Java object your just created.